# AWK does not capture Z using a regex [0-z] range

Tags: regex, awk

Using gensub in awk I noticed my capital Z does not get reckognised using the following awk line:

```
awk '{name=gensub(/[0-z]/,"succes","g",$0); print name}' range2.txt
```

On a file "range2.txt" having following text:

```
A
B
Z
```

On the Z it just returns Z instead of "succes". It will return the target if unmatched. But why is it unmatched? This kept me going in loops as I mixed my issue with some other one. I have a solution to get the work done which brought this up but I am still curious as to the why. I tried all other letters of the alfabet and numbers which all return success **except** the capital Z. This letter is more or less in the middle of the range however.

Locale charmap returned ISO-8859-15 which has the Z in the middle of the 0-z range.

I have boiled down the issue to what I just wrote down but don't see more openings. I have also used other AWK string functions as well, none of them finding the Z. i.e SPLIT MATCH GSUB.

I did try just adding the Z manually and then it works:

> awk '{name=gensub(/[0-zZ]/,"succes","g",$0); print name}' range2.txt

But still...

Comment: Can't reproduce, it's working for me... What environment are you trying it in? Are you sure there isn't any weird invisible character anywhere/the code is just as you pasted it?

Comment: i run it on Linux 2.6.32 it returns 3 succes for me, what is your locale?? mb you'll try smth like this

awk '{name=gensub(/[0-9a-zA-Z]/,"succes","g",$0); print name}' 1.txt

Comment: I am on redhat: "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.4 (Tikanga)" (Linux 2.6.18-164.el5 x86_64) My locale is ISO-8859-15 but as the capital A-Z will be grouped together and my range goes from number 0 to lower z it should wrap all Capitals up. I know the workaround but I am just curious as to why. We are one step closer however as it can not be reproduced and therefore seems a settings or distro issue. As to weird charcters, none there. Tried it on different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all input I can answer this one myself now.

LC_all=C IS actually working but it has to be exported as environment variable. So `export LC_ALL=C` (or more specifically LC_COLLATE) is what I should have issued in my console instead of just `LC_ALL=C`. The latter can be used but than only followed by the command having to be locale independent.

Awk should be locale independent since version 4 but mine is still version 3. So for me, I would still have to issue the awk like:

```
LC_ALL=C awk '{name=gensub(/[0-z]/,"succes","g",$0); print name}' range2.txt
```

or

```
LC_COLLATE=C awk '{name=gensub(/[0-z]/,"succes","g",$0); print name}' range2.txt
```

My grep uses a different locale. I cannot find where these locales are set, which would be interesting,  but I do see the different behaviours with respect to character ranges. Also grep can benefit from making it locale independent. So where in my set-up:

```
echo Z | grep [0-z]
```

returns nothing, following does return Z

```
LC_ALL echo Z | grep [0-z]
```

Answer (score 1):

The only possible answer is that the Z is NOT inside the specified range in the locale. Your locale may be broken on your distro. Try other tools like grep and sed with the same range to see if you can reproduce the problem - if so the problem is with your locale, if not it is with your awk.

Comment: Some more food for thought. Just tried `grep '[0-z]' range2.txt` which gave me not even the A and B, just nothing instead. Which made me think what you mentioned on order. It now appears Grep uses a table order 0-9a-zA-Z. Awk uses a table order 0-9aAbB..zZ (and there is the answer to the missing Z, [0-Z] gives succes on all). And finally my locale ISO-8859-15 is defined 0-9A-Za-z as per wikipedia. So **all** are different. So where the table order comes from is still hazy.

Comment: *I might post this as answer actually unless someone can see where these orders are defined.

Comment: What does `[[:alnum:]]` give you with both `grep` and `awk`? That's what we always tell people to use instead of explicit ranges to avoid locale issues so I'm curious if it works for you in your apparently seriously broken environment. At the end of the day, it's honestly just kinda hard to care about why a given character is missing from a range when you shouldn't be using a range anyway if character classes work!

Comment: That works fine, safe indeed. I had a better look at the term locale though and it seems just saying ISO-8859-15 is not cutting it. I have a whole list of say subs (as per command locale) and you can over-ride system ones by user defined ones. So awk and grep might use different locales (where I assumed first to be one locale). I start grep from /bin/grep while I start awk from /usr/bin/awk. Could this be a clue?

Comment: Beats me, I try to never write any code that's locale-dependent so I don't pay much attention to the mechanics of locales. I suppose different commands may or may not use system locale settings. That seems to be the case for you since you mentioned previously that setting LC_ALL=C had no effect. Given that, they must have some internal order they use.